# C# Math.Net - How to properly set parameters of Fit.Curve

Tags: c#, math.net

I'm trying to fit a curve for data like
[image: Saturation Plot]

What I've got so far:

```
public IList<OxyPlot.DataPoint> Points { get; private set; }

public MainViewModel()
{

    Points = new List<DataPoint>
    {
        new DataPoint(38  ,  6.5    ),
        new DataPoint(59  ,  7      ),
        new DataPoint(81  ,  8      ),
        new DataPoint(103 ,  12     ),
        new DataPoint(125 ,  12.2   ),
        new DataPoint(147 ,  16     ),
        new DataPoint(168 ,  15.5   ),
        new DataPoint(190 ,  16.5   ),
        new DataPoint(211 ,  18     ),
        new DataPoint(213 ,  19     ),
        new DataPoint(215 ,  18.5   ),
        new DataPoint(219 ,  18     ),
        new DataPoint(221 ,  19     ),
        new DataPoint(224 ,  18.8   ),
        new DataPoint(226 ,  18.3   ),
        new DataPoint(229 ,  18.4   ),
        new DataPoint(231 ,  19.2   ),
        new DataPoint(232 ,  20.4   ),
        new DataPoint(234 ,  19.1   ),
        new DataPoint(235 ,  18.4   ),
        new DataPoint(236 ,  19.8   ),
        new DataPoint(237 ,  19.2   ),
        new DataPoint(238 ,  18.9   ),
        new DataPoint(239 ,  18.8   ),
        new DataPoint(240 ,  18.2   ),
        new DataPoint(241 ,  16     ),
        new DataPoint(242 ,  12     ),
        new DataPoint(243 ,  9      ),
        new DataPoint(244 ,  5      ),
        new DataPoint(245 ,  2      ),
        new DataPoint(246 ,  1      ),
        new DataPoint(247 ,  0      ),
        new DataPoint(248 ,  0      ),
    };


    var f = new Func<double, double, double, double>((x, A, B) => A * x + B * x + A * B * x * x);

    var result = Fit.Curve(Points.Select(p => p.X).ToArray(), Points.Select(p => p.Y).ToArray(),  f , 20.0) ;
```

With the short API explanation on https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics/Fit.htm it isn't clear enough to me what are the parameters

```
Func<double, double, double> f,
```

and

```
double initialGuess
```

Comment: 1) If you don't get an answer here, perhaps the people over at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) would be able to help. 2) Is it a curve, or is it a linear relationship with a cutoff point?

Comment: Given "Non-linear least-squares fitting the points (x,y) to an arbitrary function y : x -> f(p, x), returning its best fitting parameter p," `initialGuess` will be your initial guess at the value of p. Say you knew that y=a(x*x) and 2.7 < a < 2.9, then you could give it an initial guess of 2.8.